# Is there a performance penalty for retrieving the primary key as part of a "WHERE PrimaryKey =" SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, primary-key

Using the premise of a `session` table with 3 columns: `id`, `skey` and `sdata`, and a `SELECT` query on that table. I have 3 options for `SELECT [...] WHERE id = 1`:

1. `"SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE id = 1"`
2. `"SELECT id, skey, sdata FROM sessions WHERE id = 1"`
3. `"SELECT skey, sdata FROM sessions WHERE id = 1"`

Solution 2 uses specific columns, avoiding the less performance friendly `*`. Though in this case, unless some one would like to specify otherwise, they would seem equivalent in performance. In this case, I'd opt for option 1 because it makes for a shorter query and I am retrieving all columns anyway.

My real question however is whether option 3 has any performance benefit on the database server side. Given that I already have the primary key, I can easily reassign it to the query Result Set afterwards, and do not *technically* need to retrieve that column at all.

Beside the minimal impact on packet size, I can't really tell from current knowledge if the needless primary key *retrieval* of 1 and 2 affects much of the performance of the query itself.

Comment: `id = 1`, you already know it. Why select it again? Anyway, db engine does not need to do more job to accomplish 2nd query compared to 3rd (apart of sending more data, but it's another story).

Comment: Are you asking a theoretical question, or are you actually facing a problem?

Comment: Why is * "less performance friendly" - in general and in this specific case? (It's good programming practice to specify columns, mainly because of forward compatibility!)

Comment: @zerkms That's my point for asking. But there is a small cost of reassignment with the way I create my object, with a PrimaryKey exception. So I am assessing the pros and cons either way. And I can best make that jugment by knowing a little more about the SQL cost difference.

Comment: "That's my point for asking." --- it's not the place you need to ever optimize. Use whichever better suits your task.

Comment: @jarlh Forward compatibility with what? If a field is added later, the code breaks. How is that more compatible? Across database types?

Comment: Well, a person that cares of forward compatibility and such stuff does not rely on the position of the columns in a result set. So argument about forward compatibility is usually more theoretical rather then practical. So to get "If a field is added later, the code breaks" you need to intentionally write terrible code.

Comment: Many databases live for decades. Tables, columns and indexes etc are added once in a while. If you have select *, your application will break, if you have specified columns that part of the application will work as before. (And other parts may use the added column!)

Comment: @jarlh "If you have select *, your application will break" --- why would it?

Comment: @zerkms I wasn't talking about field positions, but I entirely disagree with jarlh, especially in the context of my OOP architecture. If you can qualify the "db engine does not need to do more job" comment as an answer with some SQL reference or citations as to why it's very small that would be ideal.

Comment: Well, depending on programming API... If the application suddenly gets an extra column returned, or the columns come in another order, lots of things can happen...

Comment: @jarlh: only a crazy or stupid developer relies on order of columns. So if one does - they have more serious problems, than using `SELECt *`

Comment: @hexalys you unlikely will get an exact quote for such a case - you just need to understand how databases and optimizer work. Basically - if `id` was used in `WHERE` clause (regardless if it's covered by index or not) - returning it in a result set will be "free" because it's already there, so database engine does not need to do anything additional to retrieve it.

Comment: @zerkms, yes, I agree. And I don't use select * in programming, I specify columns in INSERT, I don't use natural joins etc.

Comment: If you want to find "the answer" [disable the cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-in-select.html) and benchmark each query. Spoiler: You won't find any measurable difference between any of the queries in the question; don't waste time on [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization).

Comment: @AD7six There is no such thing as premature optimization in my book. Only immature optimization.  Willingness to seek and understand the fundamentals of one's profession is *never* a waste of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. 2 and 3 should not be different performance-wise.

If you notice a difference then it could be retrieving from cache and has nothing to do with the query.

Except of course when you send the resultset to a client(browser), in which case you want to minimize the amount of data in the resultset.

Choosing between 2 and 3 basically depends on the where clause, i.e. if the id argument can be a wildcard, then include id in your select. Or when using the resultset somewhere in your code where you no longer have access to what id you used as the argument at time of retrieval.

Comment: Thanks for the added context. I did presume little difference. But I wanted to verify that assumption. I ran a few test, and I am indeed not seeing any noticeable difference. Reassigning the id to the Result Set comes pretty much cost free too. I'll mostly stick with 1, which is ideal when transfering the full data to the var opcache, and only use 3 when I need a small specific subset of columns for thing like widgets.

Answer (score 1):

As an overview to [How a RDBMS execute a query](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/630346/Understanding-how-SQL-Server-executes-a-query) from SQL-Server :

- Main thing is indexes

And

> Data in the cache (in the Buffer Pool) is shared between all queries
>   so once fetched subsequent data access operators that have to read the
>   same data will benefit from finding the data in the cache.